# Calling mint function in another contract

Tags: solidity, erc-20

I am trying to call the mint function of the reward token without inheriting it in the staking pool contract when the owner of the staking pool distributes the reward.
I am getting an error while calling distributeRewards function stating that

**the function should be payable and the value you provide should be less than the current balance**

But the function is already payable. what can I do manage miniting reward tokens in distributeRewards function without inheriting the reward token?

```
contract rewardToken{
address StakingPoolAddress = {Address of staking pool contract}
function mint(address to, uint256 amount) external {
        require(msg.sender == owner() || msg.sender == StakingPoolAddress);
         _balances[to] = _balances[to].add(amount);
         _totalSupply = _totalSupply.add(amount);
  }
}
contract StakingPool{
 mapping(address => uint256) public stakes;
IERC20 public rewardTokenAdd;
   function distributeRewards(IERC20 AddOfrewardToken )public payable onlyOwner
   {
        rewardTokenAdd = AddOfrewardToken;
       for (uint256 s = 0; s < stakeholders.length; s += 1){
           reward.mint(stakeholders[s], stakes[stakeholders[s]]);
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: That error message is quite generic it means the transaction did revert, the require might be failing or something else.

Comment: Do I need to use Delegate call here?

Comment: No, delegatecall is used to add extra functionality to a contract. Here you want the RewardToken to mint tokens to the stakeholders. Since StakingPool is calling RewardToken then it needs to be authorized to call mint.

Comment: @Ismael I have authorized the StakingPool contract but since it is a transaction function staking pool contract is unable to call mint. How can resolve this issue?

Comment: From the code in the question it should work, perhaps there's a bug in other place.

Comment: This code works fine when I remove the "require" statement from the mint function but that will make the code vulnerable.

Comment: Then the condition on the require is false `require(msg.sender == owner() || msg.sender == StakingPoolAddress)` so `msg.sender != owner` and `msg.sender != StakingPoolAddress`. Then are you sure StakingPoolAddress is updated with the correct address.